# .htaccess RewriteCond adding exception

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My RewriteCond rules rule (based on IP adress), BUT i need also to allow access to a specific file (analytics.txt) for all users.
How could i do that ? Thanks!

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR}  !^208.91.195.185
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR}  !^212.17.80.98
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/https://example.com/extranet/index.php$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^analytics\.txt$

RewriteRule .* https://example.com/extranet/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

%{REQUEST_URI} represents the domain path, part after the domain name
eg : example.com **/file** .

1)Change this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !https://example.com/extranet/index.php$
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/extranet/index.php$
```

Request_uri string starts with a leading slash, ( **/analytics.txt** ) so you need a slash in your pattern to match against the Request_uri.

2)Change this :

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^analytics\.txt$
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/analytics\.txt$
```

(Hope this helps!)